# DesignView (wrongly) complains about creating more than one System.Windows.Application instance

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

In my WPF Windows app, I have a binding in XAML that works just fine but DesignView complains about it.  I can't figure out why.

1. I wanted to share common app behavior among several different applications so I created an abstract base class "AppBase", derived from System.Windows.Application and put it in a shared assembly
2. Then, in my main application Assembly, I declared a simple App class to derive from this shared AppBase class.
3. In my main window (in that same app assembly), I bound a combo-box to an Observable collection exposed by AppBase.
4. I ran the app and the binding worked.

Great, right?  But no matter what I do, DesignView doesn't like it. When I look at the XAML, it puts the blue "squiggly line" under it.  When I hover over that squiggly, it complains

***Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain***

Yet as I mentioned, the app runs and the binding does work.  Is this just something that I have to live with?

Incidentally here's the binding

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox"
          MinWidth="80"
          Margin="2, 2"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cameras, Source={x:Static ac:AppBase.CurrentApp}}"
          Padding="2" />
```

I should note that "ac" is the namespace alias for the shared assembly in which AppBase lives and "CurrentApp" is a static property on the AppBase class that simply returns System.Windows.Application downcast to AppBase

Anyway while I can live with this if it's just an erroneous error message, it does worry me a bit.  Is there anyway to eliminate it...?

Comment: The design view tends to do this at times, but it's often down to an incorrectly assigned value, or a value which can't be parsed correctly at design time. I've seen so many issues of this nature in various applications that I now tend to ignore them. You could try defining the `AppBase` reference as a static resource by adding a `StaticExtension` tag in your `Resources` for the control. This should be parsable by the designer, so may solve the problem. I'm afraid I'm not able to test this at the moment though.

Comment: i think that when you run in design mode visual studio create a host, and then with the binding it try to create a second one...so seens normal. What is wrong is more the binding your are doing on the appclass...this is not a viewmodel :-( you'd better create a singleton class that holds your cameras which than as nothing to do with appclass

Comment: Thanks to both of you.   GCamel, you are right about my breaking the ViewModel paradigm here, but in this case, I think creating yet another singleton for the sole purpose of exposing a collection feels like foolish consistency;  Implementing the pattern only for the sake of a pattern rather than for any sort of modularity or model/view separation.  

My AppBase is a singleton I'm stuck with.  It is always going to be there.  It seems like this is a case in which MVVM gets in the way, rather than helps.